# Cache a webpage on the iPhone with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I load a web page when internet is available and cache it for offline use and it updates to the latest version when internet becomes available again?

Answer (score 1):

I assume some basic skills are available. This is a general outline.

Get the webpage using:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:yoururl];
```

If successful, store the file locally using:

```
-(NSString*)cacheFile
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cached.html"];
}

[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
               createFileAtPath:[self cacheFile] contents:data attributes:nil];
```

let the webview show the local page:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self cacheFile]
                       options:nil error:nil];

[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html"
         textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:yoururl];
```

Don't know if you can get away with all the `nil` pointers I put in here, but if it doesn't work just look up the docs. And *do* add some checking of return values...

Comment: how and where do you check whether internet is available?

Comment: The request simply fails, I think, returning `nil`. Otherwise you maybe need to take the more elaborate road of `+ (id)dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr`, which would be more verbose on what goes wrong.